# Object with reference count equals to 0 is still persistent

Tags: objective-c, ios, memory-leaks, instruments, reference-counting

I am trying to enhance the memory allocation in my non-ARC app.
There are some objects that, even if their reference count are 0, they are listed as persistent object between two heapshot.

This is my heapshot view: [image]

Lets take for instance the selected LSBookChapter in the 1st heapshot (0x6deb180).
This is the history of that object:

[image]

Why that object isn't deallocated? If the reference count is 0 I can't figure out when I over retained that object..

Comment: If you're looking for leaks, why not just use the leaks tool? Allocations is showing you that you did it _right_, not wrong.

Comment: `I am trying to the memory optimization in my non-ARC app` which involves more than just leaks.

Comment: CodaFi: The Leaks tool was not showing leaks in that area, anyway as you can see, the memory is still increasing..

Jack Boy: Can you be more helpful in this way?

Comment: @CodaFi first, no need for that kind of attitude here on stackoverflow. We are trying to contribute to same thing: help  the person that asked a question. Second, there are cases where you don't have leaks, and you still have memory problems. I can give you one example: UIWebView caching. It doesn't show as a leak (as it shouldn't), and you will have memory problems because of the increasing size. Keeping reference to classes you are no longer using is also a problem (and it's not related to memory leaking).

Comment: Not to mention that Leaks is actually pretty useless beyond identifying obvious leaks.  There are tons of ways to accrete memory that'll lead to application failure, but not show up in leaks.  When you are finished fixing the leaks identified problem, you've typically barely begun to fix your memory usage.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In my previous application, I had some concerns as you are having right now because, I didn't had leaks, but the memory was growing. After some research I stumbled upon [this](http://www.friday.com/bbum/2010/10/17/when-is-a-leak-not-a-leak-using-heapshot-analysis-to-find-undesirable-memory-growth/). I did tried to make some shortcuts on his article, but in the end I just read the whole thing to actually understand what was wrong. And YES, I was able to pinpoint every problem I had. And I might say I had quite a few.

For your particular problem, I didn't do what you are you trying right now: seeing the retainCount of an object in different heapshots. I think it's a waste of time honestly. My main goal is to make sure that if I do something and I reverse it, the memory should not increase or if it does it should be slightly (quick example: going into a new `UIViewController` and press the button back).

Answer (score 6):

Might you have zombie detection turned on?

Zombie detection causes nothing to be deallocated, but -- likely -- the retain count will drop to zero and, more usefully, you'll see a one to one correspondence between retain causing and release causing events.

---

Also, if you don't turn on "only track live allocations", then you'll see the object in Instruments after it is deallocated, with a 0 retain count, but it is really deallocated.